# Find the most recently modifed folder

Tags: perl

`$some_folder` will always be in `~/foo/bar/`. `$some_folder` will always be the most recently modified folder inside `~/foo/bar/`, however, the name will never be the same per-system. How would I go about finding `$some_folder`?

Comment: `ls -1dt */ | head -n 1` will give you most recently modified folder.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a moment to read [ask].

Comment: Thanks! That worked.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's tagged `perl`, so I'm going to assume you want some `perl` code. But as  [Chankey Pathak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257635/chankey-pathak) notes in the comments:

```
ls -1dt */ | head -n 1
```

Will do the trick.

In `perl` you'll want `stat` and `glob` and probably `sort`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %files_by_mtime;

foreach my $file ( glob ( "~/foo/bar/*" ) ) {
   next unless -d $file;
   my ( $mtime ) = (stat($file))[9];
   $files_by_mtime{$file} = $mtime; 
}

foreach my $filename (  sort { $files_by_mtime{$b} <=> $files_by_mtime{$a} } keys %files_by_mtime ) {
   print "$filename  $files_by_mtime{$filename }\n";
}
```

Generates an ordered list - by mtime.

To simplify this - you can just access element zero:

```
print "".(  sort { $files_by_mtime{$b} <=> $files_by_mtime{$a} } keys %files_by_mtime )[0],"\n";
```

Or simpifying to a one liner:

```
perl -e '%f = map { -d ? $_ => (stat)[9] : () } glob("~/foo/bar/*");print "" . ( sort { $f{$b} <=> $f{$a} } keys %f )[0];
```